# How to get the value only from mySQL so the query result is not inside a table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

So my query is:

```
select exists (select * from visit where time like "April 17%") as 'res';
```

And it returns this:

```
+--------------+
|          res |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

How do I get it to return 1 only? 
This is useful for people using mySQL and node:

```
app.post('/qr', function(req, res) {
console.log("Check QR code.");
let now = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
let subnow = now.substr(0, 8);
let subnowwild = subnow + "%";
connection.query("select exists (select * from visit where time like ?)", subnowwild, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
  if(result = 0) {
    res.redirect(307, '/savedata');
  }
  else {
    res.redirect(307, '/updatedata');
  }
});
});
```

Just to explain my code, it redirects the page to different routes depending on the result of the query. It's nice just to see if you're working on the same thing I am and getting confused about the process.

Anyway, you can see the result needs to be 0 to save the data, but it is returning the value inside the table instead. This would be useful if you want to do different stuff with the data depending on what it returns but I just need the return value outside of the table.

Comment: Two questions - (a) Why are you using `result = 0`? This will always return `true`, as `0` is being *assigned* to `result` as opposed to being compared to `result`. (b) Have you tried to grab the result out of the `result` structure using something like `result[0]["count(fname)"]`?

Comment: THANKS! I'm not very good at linking previous information I know and applying it elsewhere. My thinking is very compartmentalised. But I didn't realise things like accessing arrays can apply to mySQL. I just assumed it was a special command. So result[0].res returns the value. If you would like to post that answer I will choose you as best, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab the result you're looking for out of the `result` variable:

```
result[0].res
```

Comment: Hi esqew! I was wondering if you could help with the redirect problem I am having with this code? Where it says `console.log(result);` if I change it to req.body it works but it won't post with that information. So inside the if result = 0, (or if result[0].res = 0 now) the body is no longer the json object I want it to be, it doesn't exist after the mysql connection. But I want to keep the same post info in my redirect. If you could help that'd be great! I can also post another question with the same and you could answer that if you'd like (:

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons. A single `=` is assigning a value to the variable.

Comment: THANK YOU! I keep getting confused with mySQL using only `=` once? Is that correct? Thank you so much either way.

Comment: Yes, MySQL differs from most programming/scripting syntaxes by using a single `=` for its comparisons.